# jquery click function .. apply in all span

Tags: jquery, wordpress, this, advanced-custom-fields

jquery click function .. apply in all span, already checked the code, but this all set as THIS..

Exemple in: http://jsfiddle.net/dualdesign/8TBC3/9/

Code Jquery:

```
function DropDown(el) {
    this.dd = el;
    this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span');
    this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdown > li');
    this.val = '';
    this.index = -1;
    this.initEvents();
}

    DropDown.prototype = {
       initEvents : function() {
          var obj = this;
          obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
             $(this).toggleClass('active');
             return false;
          });

          obj.opts.on('click',function(){
             var opt = $(this);
             obj.val = opt.text();
             obj.index = opt.index();
             obj.placeholder.text(obj.val);
          });
       },

       getValue : function() {
          return this.val;
       },
       getIndex : function() {
          return this.index;
       }
    }

    $(function() {
       var dd = new DropDown( $('.wrapper-dropdown-5') );
       $(document).click(function() {
          // all dropdowns
          $('.wrapper-dropdown-5').removeClass('active');
       });
    });
```

I am populating this HTML dynamically, so have several divs. Wrapper-dropdown-5 ..

Code HTML com ACF plugin for wordpress:

```
<div id="select" class="wrapper-dropdown-5" tabindex="1">
     <span><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right"></i> <?php echo $first_row['zamba-var']; ?></span>
    <ul class="dropdown">
    <?php while(has_sub_field('zamba-detalhes')): ?>
        <li><a href="#"><?php the_sub_field('zamba-var'); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
   </ul>
</div>
```

In this same example, I want to use data values ​​to include the text in p, following ..

```
<div class="wrapper-dropdown-5">
    <span><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right"></i> <?php echo $first_row['zamba-var']; ?></span>
    <ul class="dropdown">
    <?php while(has_sub_field('zamba-detalhes')): ?>
        <li><a href="#" data-var="<?php the_sub_field('zamba-var'); ?>" data-varvalor="<?php the_sub_field('zamba-varvalor'); ?>" data-vardesc="<?php the_sub_field('zamba-vardesc'); ?>"><?php the_sub_field('zamba-var'); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried this code, no result..

Code Jquery:

```
function DropDown(el) {
    this.dd = el;
    this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span');
    this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdown > li');
    this.val = '';
    this.index = -1;
    this.initEvents();

    valor = this.opts.data('varvalor');
    desc = this.opts.data('vardesc');
}

    DropDown.prototype = {
       initEvents : function() {
          var obj = this;
          obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
             $(this).toggleClass('active');
             return false;
          });

          obj.opts.on('click',function(){
             var opt = $(this);
             obj.val = opt.text();
             obj.index = opt.index();
             obj.placeholder.text(obj.val);

             obj.opts.next('p.varvalor').text(valor);
             obj.opts.next().next('p.vardesc').text(desc);

          });
       },

       getValue : function() {
          return this.val;
       },
       getIndex : function() {
          return this.index;
       }
    }

    $(function() {
       var dd = new DropDown( $('.wrapper-dropdown-5') );
       $(document).click(function() {
          // all dropdowns
          $('.wrapper-dropdown-5').removeClass('active');
       });
    });
```

Comment: so you want a click event on all the spans in your page?

Comment: Add code html, was poorly explained..

Comment: you need to create a `DropDown` instance for each `wrapper-dropdown-5` element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an instance of `DropDown` object for each `.wrapper-dropdown-5` element. Because each dropdown has its own state(like the selected item, it's index etc)

```
$('.wrapper-dropdown-5').each(function () {
    var dd = new DropDown($(this));
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7E9HF/)

Comment: Could you also help me in this other question?

Comment: @dualdesign sure what is it

Comment: I add more code, i tested with .next() for change de text of p class varvalor and vardesc, and don't work..